# How to remove hoses that are clamped to a water manifold in a hot-tub

Tags: plumbing, pipe, hose, hot-tub

I have a hot tub and a hose of the water manifold cracked off (see below on the second hose from the left that is separated from the manifold, but a part of the manifold is broken off inside).

Since the manifold is broken, I need to replace it. To do this I'll need to remove all the hoses. As you can see below in the red circle there are clamps holding the hoses on. However, the clamps aren't the issue. When removing these clamps, the hoses are still stuck to the manifold.

Any advice on how to remove the hoses (plus the broken part inside the loose hose) from this manifold would be greatly appreciated.

I thought maybe I could try cutting the hoses (not sure whith what), but was worried that they would no longer be long enough.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should just replace all the hoses as well as the manifold, if the hoses are so set/stiff with age that they cannot be moved. That tends to be a step on the path to cracking and leaking. One big repair .vs. lots of smaller repairs over time.

You could try dunking the whole mess in hot water or using a hair dryer/heat gun to warm them up and make them more pliable.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case you can cut them then get a short length of hose and use these http://brasscomponents.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Barbed-Brass-Hose-Coupler.jpg.

You could also use a dental pick to shove some lubricant (dish soap) into the space between the hose and the manifold that might loosen it up.